# java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset: next

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I didn't find the reason for a SQLExeption, I got it at `while(dbrs.next())`. It is simple, it was working, but after update to Oracle Server 19, I got this error. I got still a result set in Oracle Developer with the same account.

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
if (Oracle){
  ResultSet dbrs = st.executeQuery("select table_name from all_tables");
  while(dbrs.next()){
     if (dbrs.getString(1).equals(G_IN)){
        st.execute("DROP TABLE "+G_IN);
        System.out.println(G_IN+" gelöscht");
     }
  }
  dbrs.close();
}else{
   String loeschen="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \"" + G_IN +"\"";
   System.out.println(loeschen);
   st.execute( loeschen );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't reuse a Statement object as is the case in your while loop. To execute a new query, you need to use a new Statement object.

Replace

```
st.execute("DROP TABLE " + G_IN);
```

with

```
conn.createStatement().execute("DROP TABLE " + G_IN);
```

and it should work.

Comment: The OP shouldn't only make sure to use a separate statement, they must also ensure that auto-commit mode is disabled.

Comment: With this solution how will you close the new Statement?

Comment: no, this was not the reason. I got the same error.

Comment: @Chris94 This is an on-the-fly object that's eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: it was working with  ResultSet dbrs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select table_name from all_tables"); plus conn.createStatement().execute("DROP TABLE "+G_IN);

Comment: @v.montag Glad it worked.